# Текст в соответствии с макетом

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! У никак не могу подогнать текст в соответствии с макетом, прикрепляю HTML и CSS разметку, благодарен за любую помощь!

Нужно чтобы текст был по центру относительно блока

HTML:

```
        <div class="block">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p class="onblock">Моя жизнь</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p class="onblock">Это работает</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p class="onblock">Всё как у людей</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-heart-o {
    border: 5px solid #242424;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-width: thin;
    margin-top: 70px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-heart-o:hover{
    color: #249cce;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border: 2px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
    border: 5px solid #292929;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-width: thin;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.fa-toggle-on:hover{
    color: #249cce;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border: 2px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up {
    border: 5px solid #292929;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-width: thin;
    margin-top: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up:hover{
    color: #249cce;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border: 2px solid #249cce;
}

p.onblock {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.313em;
    color: #404040;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Что имею ныне]

[image: Нужный результат]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте! В последнем правиле свойство `text-align: center;` не работает. Всё из-за свойства inline-block. Ширина `<p>` здесь идет не на весь родительский блок, а вычисляется автоматически, в зависимости от размера текста. Вот и прижат текст к левому краю.

Чтобы заработало, надо либо ширину `<p>` явно указать `width: 100%;`, либо `display: block` вместо `display: inline-block`.
Но тогда у вас могут иконки могут оказаться не по центру, и центрировать придется уже их.

Хорошо бы ссылку на страницу с проблемой, или хотя бы полный код CSS. А то здесь не все стили для позиционирования приведены.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понятно, вы просто не обозначили ширину элемента: например

```
.col-xs-12{
    width: 200px; /*например*/
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.onblock{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Если у него подключен бутстрап, там уже все будет проставлено

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев , я исхожу из приведённого примера кода, "может, как то и где то быть что то"   это не для SO. Тут телепатов нет и просто, исходя из наличия бутстраповских классов, трудно угадать что там может ещё быть, нестандартного оверстайла, вне бутстрапа и т.д
Мой пример - это  "тыканием пальцем" на возможную(!) проблему. ))